# Erro ao gerar Build do projeto Angular

Tags: angular

Eu tenho um projeto para fins didáticos de locadora de veículos. Já gerei o arquivo WAR do projeto do Back End, agora preciso gerar os arquivos do Angular.

Porém, quando eu vou gerar o build do meu projeto, através do comando "ng build", ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Progress Plugin Invalid Options

options['colors'] is an invalid additional property
options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
options should match exactly one schema in oneOf

ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

options['colors'] is an invalid additional property
options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
options should match exactly one schema in oneOf

    at validateOptions (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\schema-utils\src\validateOptions.js:31:11)
    at new ProgressPlugin (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:90:3)
    at Object.getCommonConfig (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\common.js:
123:27)
    at BrowserBuilder.buildWebpackConfig (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js:74:31)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.rxjs_1.of.pipe.operators_1.concatMap [as project] (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\brows
er\index.js:31:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:65:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:55:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at TapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:62:26)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:84:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:25:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at ForkJoinSubscriber.notifyComplete (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\rxjs\internal\observable\forkJoin.js:79:25)
    at InnerSubscriber._complete (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:32:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\projetoTCC\projetoClient\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:76:18)
```

Alguém já enfrentou o mesmo problema, ou saberia me dizer o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi!

Qual a versão do angular, do npm e do webpack ?

Sobre o webpack Dá uma olhada neste arquivo:

> \projetoClient\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\common.js

Alterar: 
de:

```
extraPlugins.push(new ProgressPlugin({ profile: buildOptions.verbose, colors: true }));
```

para:

```
extraPlugins.push(new ProgressPlugin({ profile: buildOptions.verbose }));
```

Eu achei neste [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12866)

Comment: As versões que estou utilizando são:
Versão do NPM 6.4.1
Angular CLI 7.2.2
Fiz a alteração que você mencionou, mas quando rodo o projeto ele apresenta um erro bem no arquivo alterado. @dalmo.santos

Comment: Agora fui dar uma olhada melhor no link que colocou em sua resposta, e consegui resolver o problema colocando o WebPack nas dependências do "package.json". Valeww